# Split receptacle

Tags: wiring

Just talk to a retired electrician at Home Depot and he said that on a split receptacle you can have two different copper circuit gauge wires. Forgot to ask if he meant single pole or double pole. From what we were originally talking he said it can be done on any receptacle. He insist that it can be done and has. I didn't even asked about 2 pole (switch and receptacle). Do you agree. I didn't see anything in NEc to the contrary? Last time on this subject. Thank u all.

Comment: Do we know what? A split receptacle, by definition, is supplied by two hot wires.

Comment: Yes I do know what a split receptacle is...the question is do you know what it is  (single pole) besides one switch leg controls one outlet by a switch while the other has power with usually the same circuit gauge. Also do you know about a double pole split receptacle? I'm asking for help and mostly everyone has been great.

Comment: You keep asking this question over and over and over in slightly different forms.   It would be better if you went back and edited to refine your similar questions instead of asking near-dupe questions.  When you edit your question, that creates a "bump" to the top, so there is no need to re-ask to get a bump.  This is not a chatroom with questions going away, this archives questions forever, so redundant questions really clutter up the site. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe so. I have deleted a couple. The problem is that I asked the questions but it appears that you don't' k ow and if so then kindly tell me. As I indicated I'm done asking about split receptacles from here. As I indicated I'm trying to get help which I thought stack was about and where I come from if you dont know something then say it. I even sent pictures to that was to no avail. So again I will not ask stack about splits any longer. Most of the people again here have been helpful and kind. And if you did read my splits they were different type of questions. sorry I'm not in your league.

Answer (score 1):

A split receptacle simply has the tab on the brass (hot) side broken off, or both tabs broken off even, so it can be fed by two hots (either a switched + an unswitched or the two legs of a MWBC if only the hot side is broken off, or two *completely separate circuits* if both tabs are broken off).

You could have 14AWG going to one and 12AWG going to the other if you were in conduit, or if you had both tabs broken and two cables going to the receptacle.  Otherwise, it'd be impossible to do so without violating 300.3(B)/310.10(H).

Comment: Thank you so very much.. I did forget about mentioning removing the tab and appreciate your kind advice. I had an electrician seven yrs ago put a new panel and changed  a couple of receptacles. The problem why I asked this question was because I have a 20 amp circuit that this is connected to which is fine except that same circuit breaker is connected to mostly 14 gauge receptacles and outlets (approx 16). So when I was upgrading. These receptacles this is where I found the split (14 and 12 for power). I was told at first okay and then immediately change that breaker to 15 and rewire. Thank U

Comment: You were the first who was so kind in breaking this down for me and I reallly appreciate it. I wish others would understand that us neophytes are teing and people like you and a few others make it easier to understand. Even Home Depot and menards aren't as sharp as you guts. Thanks again. Larry

Comment: I agree with 3phase +.  @Larry pinky, if you like an answer please up vote it that will give thanks and help reputation. Since you have asked the question when you up vote it a green check mark identifies the question is answered.